# What is the use of namespace and am I using it is the right way?

Tags: php, namespaces, constants

I want to know that why the `namespace` is used what is the advantage and disadvantages of using it. If it is for just declaring constant then we can also use `define()` and `constant` or is it used for security reasons.

How can I use it if I have three files a, b and c respectively inside that function naming _a, _b and _c respectively?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`namespace` is used to solve a very common problem that is often found while using reusable code. You can use define and constant for defining but you will do it on same page. As u know words like controller class and many common words like this are used in nearly every language framework. And we use use integrated environment for our complex use. So these words may clash. using namespace ensures where we have to look first for the definitions of functions and words used below the namespace declaration.

Comment: does thing also used for functions

Comment: yes, Everything that is defined under that namespace is there. Mostly all the  default functions but you can also have custom defined functions. This is how the frameworks work. custom functions are defined in custom namespaces importing default functions of the language and it makes our work easier

Comment: Last thing to know if I have three files a, b and c respectively inside that function naming _a, _b and _c respectively as I described above but in these three files I have to define namespace with three different names  ( means if in a,b and c file have namespace like this a_space, b_space and c_space respectively ) is it right or worng

Comment: It is not wrong, But you should be clever while  creating different namespaces in same project. It will create confusion for you. You have other options too for function override and other option, depending on what you want to accomplish. **Bottomline**: It is not wrong, but you should avoid creating many custom namespace in single project.